# Combobox dropdown list is going below the window screen.

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am using a DatagridView in which I have some 16 rows with each row having a combobox in it. The problem arise when I try to drop down the combobox in the bottom most row which has around 20- 30 items in it. The scroll bar  in the dropdown disappears and the dropdown goes below the windows screen area. Any possible solution for it so the dropdown opens to the top. 
Framework 2.0.

Comment: Winform or WPF or Asp.Net or Silverlight?

Answer (score 1):

I am unable to duplicate the problem. I tried moving this window around and opening various combo boxes. If it doesn't fit to drop down, it drops up, therefore being entirely on screen.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class MainForm : Form
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new MainForm());
    }

    public MainForm()
    {
        string[] comboSource = Enumerable.Range(1, 30).Select(i => String.Format("Item #{0}", i)).ToArray();

        Controls.Add(new DataGridView
        {
            AutoGenerateColumns = false,
            Columns = { new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn { HeaderText = "Item", DataSource = comboSource }, },
            DataSource = comboSource, // just adding dummy items for effect
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
        });
    }
}
```

Can you produce a similarly simple example that does duplicate the problem?

Comment: I am facing this problem only on Windows XP, on windows 7 its works perfectly alright without any change in code. As the dropdownlist has more than 16 items scroll bar pops ups the first time we click the combobox dropdown, but if we click that again the scrollbar disappears and the controls just go below the visible screen area making it near to impossible to select the needed item.Any idea why that happens?

Comment: I guess the combobox control on XP is broken? I've not encountered this before myself. It may be possible to perform the boundary checking yourself just before the in-place ComboBox is made visible and move it.